# Where Does ギブソンタック Come from?

Tags: words

I recently ran into this term, which is apparently a hairstyle (Google has some images if you need). Does anyone know:

1. How it is meant to be Romanized (Gibson Tack? Gibson Tac/k?)
2. Where the term comes from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a Gibson tuck, named after artist Charles Dana Gibson's "Gibson Girl".

*Tuck* here is just the English word *tuck*, which I assume you're familiar with.  Here's a summary from [a random website I found on Google](https://kinarino.jp/cat5-%E7%BE%8E%E5%AE%B9%E3%83%BB%E3%82%B1%E3%82%A2/8462-%E8%B6%85%E7%B0%A1%E5%8D%98%E3%81%AA%E3%81%AE%E3%81%AB%E5%8F%AF%E6%84%9B%E3%81%84%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A8%E3%82%81%E9%AB%AA%E2%99%A5%E3%80%8C%E3%82%AE%E3%83%96%E3%82%BD%E3%83%B3%E3%82%BF%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%80%8D%E3%81%AE%E7%B4%A0%E6%95%B5%E3%81%AA%E3%83%98%E3%82%A2%E3%82%A2%E3%83%AC%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B8):

> ギブソンタックは、19世紀のアメリカの画家、チャールズ・ダナ・ギブソンが描く女性が「ギブソン・ガール」が由来。ギブソンの描くギブソンガールは、美しく自立した女性像として19世紀の終わりから20世紀初頭に、アメリカの多くの女性の間で支持を得たのだそう。タック（tuck）は「入れ込む」という意味があり、内側に髪の毛を入れ込んでいることから。「ギブソンロール」とも呼ばれます。

You can find more about it in English by searching for "Gibson tuck".